# install_name_tool can't use change "because larger updated load commands do not fit"

Tags: ld, dylib, libtool, install-name-tool

I need to relink a file with the `install_name_tool`. The file in question let me change one of the dylib paths, but when I change the second (of 7), I get this error:

```
install_name_tool: changing install names or rpaths can't be redone for: some/library (for architecture i386) because larger updated load commands do not fit (the program must be relinked, and you may need to use -headerpad or -headerpad_max_install_names)
```

After googling around I found that there simply is not enough room for the new paths within the file, and that I might be able to use the `ld` tool, or the `libtool` to fix this. However, I am not able to figure out how. I do not have the source code for this library, so I cannot recompile it.

Is there *any* way for me to update all the dylib paths for this file? Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

I am on osx 10.10
The command I am using: `install_name_tool -change old/dylib/path.dylib new/dylib/path.dylib file/to/update`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in your binary, not the libraries. Do what the warning suggests. Add `-headerpad_max_install_names` to the ld flags used to link your binary. If you are using Xcode, you can put it in your target's Other Linker Flags build setting.

Comment: I build my c++ dynamic lib my.so using make and then correct the paths via install_name_tool. After some changes in the source files I received the message.Where need I do changes to fix it?

Comment: Your makefile will have someway to set compiler flags. You add it there.